# Showing a matrix with all ones except on the diagonal is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show an $n\times n$ matrix that takes the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & x_2 & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}$$

is invertible? Each $x_i$ is a strictly positive integer and all other entries are one. I also know that none of the $x_i$'s are equal to $1$, but I'm not sure if this constraint is needed. I tried to use induction but failed. Maybe there is some easier way.

Comment: Certainly not invertible if all the $x_i$ are equal to $1$. And you say all other entries are zero... you probably mean one. Can you update your question?

Comment: if all the $1$'s were instead zeros, then  it would be  invertible

Comment: add all of the information you have about the entries of the matrix in your post

Comment: You can try induction & Sylvester's criterion, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: You should say something about your field -- the claim breaks when your field has positive characteristic (e.g. select $\mathbb F_p$ with $n-2=p$ and $x_1=x_2=...= x_n = 2$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use positive definite property of the matrix: if for all $i$, $x_i>1$ the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & x_2 & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}=J+D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive diagonal and $J$ all one matrix. So $A\ge D$ and all eigenvalues are strictly positive.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_i$ be the $i$th column vector of your matrix, call it $J$. Suppose there are $n$ scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i=\vec{0}$$

Then we would have $$a_ix_i +a_i(n-1)=a_i(x_i+n-1)=0$$  for each $i$. Since $1\leq n$, then $1-n\leq 0$ so we cannot have $x_i=1-n\leq 0$. We must then have $a_i=0$ for all $i$, hence all of the columns of $J$ are linearly independent. Use rank-nullity to finish it off.

Answer (score 1):

$D=\mathrm{diag}(x_1-1,\ldots,x_n-1)$ is positive definite as well as $$D+J_n=D+1_n1_n^{^T}=D^{1/2}(I_n+(D^{-1/2}1_n)(D^{-1/2}1_n){^T}))D^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The result is more general (you do not need them to be positive) and this proof will show what condition you have to put over the $x_1,...x_n$

I am going to prove that the kernel of this matrix is zero. Consider the homogeneous system of that matrix with unknowns $y_1,...,y_n$. Then, the $i$-th equation of that system is $$x_iy_i + \sum_{j \neq i} y_j = 0.$$ Adding an substracting $y_i$ we get $$(x_i-1)y_i + \sum_{j} y_j = 0,$$ so $$(x_i-1)y_i = - \sum_{j} y_j$$ and this for all $i = 1,...,n$, so we find the relation $$(x_i - 1)y_i = (x_1 - 1)y_1$$ for all $i = 1,...,n$. Since $x_i \neq 1$ for $i = 2,...n$, we can solve $$y_i = \frac{x_1-1}{x_i-1} y_1.$$

Using again the first equation with $i = 1$ we have that $$x_1y_1 + \sum_{j \neq 1} y_j = x_1y_1 + \sum_{j \neq 1} \frac{x_1-1}{x_j-1} y_1 = \left(x_1 + \sum_{j \neq 1} \frac{x_1-1}{x_j-1} \right) y_1 = 0$$

So if the term in parenthesis is not zero (in your case your $x_i$'s are all greater than one so this happens, but you need much less than that), $y_1 = 0$ and by my forth equation, $y_i = 0$ for all $i = 1,...,n$.

This implies that the kernel is trivial and therefore the matrix is invertible.